How to render a custom template for 403 page
I have a function that checks whether the current user is authorized to access the URL. I attach it to the router via add_condition:
use Mojolicious::Lite;

# Adding a custom condition
app->routes->add_condition(auth => sub {
    my ($route, $c, $captures, $num) = @_;

    $c->res->code(403);
    $c->rendered(403);
    # Here, you could define your condition. For example, check if a parameter is set.
    return 0;  # true/false depending on parameter
});

my $r = app->routes;
$r->get('/block')->requires(auth => 1)->to(cb => sub {
  my $c = shift;
  $c->render(template => 'default');
});

# Route for home
get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->render(template => 'main');
};

# Default template
app->start;

__DATA__

@@ 403.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Default Template</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to the Default Template</h1>
<p>This is the default template.</p>
</body>
</html>

@@ main.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Main page</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to the main page</h1>
<p>The main page is here.</p>
</body>
</html>



http://127.0.0.1:3000/block - gives an empty page with 403 status code
http://127.0.0.1:3000/ - gives the main page rendered.

What should I do to use a custom template for 403 page?

Instead of $c->rendered(403); try $c->render(template => 'exception.development.403');

@HåkonHægland No, calling $c->render inside a condition function gives an error: "Could not render a response". Probably, it should be called inside controller function.

@HåkonHægland I added a MWE, please look.

Thanks for the MWE. I tried using $c->render(template => 'forbidden', status => 403); inside the condition function. And it worked fine here. Also added a @@ forbidden.html.ep template in the DATA section.

@HåkonHægland Yes, it works. $c->rendered(403); is not needed.

try this out! It renders a custom 403 page when access is denied.
use Mojolicious::Lite;

# Adding a custom condition
app->routes->add_condition(auth => sub {
    my ($route, $c, $captures, $num) = @_;

    # Check for authorization
    if (0) { # Replace 0 with your actual authorization logic
        return 1; # Authorized
    }

    # Unauthorized - Render the custom forbidden page with 403 status
    $c->render(template => 'forbidden', status => 403);
    return 0; # Deny access
});

my $r = app->routes;
$r->get('/block')->requires(auth => 1)->to(cb => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->render(template => 'default');
});

# Route for home
get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    $c->render(template => 'main');
};

# Start the application
app->start;

__DATA__

@@ forbidden.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
<p>You are not authorized to access this page.</p>
</body>
</html>

@@ default.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Default Template</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to the Default Template</h1>
<p>This is the default template.</p>
</body>
</html>

@@ main.html.ep
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Main page</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to the main page</h1>
<p>The main page is here.</p>
</body>
</html>

